# NoMethodError running Integration Test, RailsTutorial Ch9

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, railstutorial.org

I'm having an issue where my integration tests do not seem to find the log_in_as method from my test_helper.rb

I have been following Michael Hart's Rails tutorial, so I was hoping not to massively refactor my code to try and get this to work. I would like to continue on through the book without having to exclude the tests, since it is pretty test heavy afterall.

Error:

```
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_remembering:
NoMethodError: undefined method `log_in_as' for #<UsersLoginTest:0x00000005b18460>
    test/integration/users_login_test.rb:43:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
```

User_login_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper.rb'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

.
.
.

  test "login with remembering" do
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '1')
    assert_not_empty cookies['remember_token']
  end

  test "login without remembering" do
    # Log in to set the cookie.
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '1')
    # Log in again and verify that the cookie is deleted.
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '0')
    assert_empty cookies['remember_token']
  end
end
```

test_helper.rb:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all

  # Returns true if a test user is logged in.
  def is_logged_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
  end

  # Log in as a particular user.
  def log_in_as(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
end

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  # Log in as a particular user.
  def log_in_as(user, password: 'password', remember_me: '1')
    post login_path, params: { session: { email: user.email,
                                          password: password,
                                          remember_me: remember_me } }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. There are two problems I had to fix:

1. Make sure there is only one test_helper.rb file, and
2. test_helper.rb is in the right folder

Hope this helps!